# What is bad about throwing a more general exception?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, exception

I have this method:

```
public abstract byte[] readFile(String pPath) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException;
```

I call it like this:

```
try { readFile("/example.txt"); }
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
catch (IOException e) {}
```

I thought everything is fine. But Android Studio complains. The message is:

> There is a more general exception, 'java.io.IOException', in the throws list already.

It marks the FileNotFoundException in the method declaration gray. It suggests removing FileNotFoundException from the throws list.

Why does Android Studio complain?

Comment: Probably because your routine will never throw a FileNotFoundException but we can never really know for sure because you didn't post the code.

Comment: @JJF It complains that there is a more general exception in the throws list. It does not complain that the exception is never thrown... (I added the error message.)

Comment: Android Studio complains because `FileNotFoundException` extends `IOException`. By declaring to throw only `IOException`, users can still catch `FileNotFoundException`. In this case Android Studio is probably a bit more strict than you might want, because declaring `FNFE` explicitly does make it clearer for callers.

Comment: @RobSpoor Yes I think that too. Perhaps I should simply ignore this message...

Comment: Just remove `FileNotFoundException`, it's not needed.  `throws IOException` means that *any* exception extending `IOException` may be thrown, which includes `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: @Olivier When I do this my code will loose precision. The caller will no longer know that this method can definitely throw a FileNotFoundException.

Comment: It's also probably because both `catch` blocks are exactly the same (both empty). Once you write something into the blocks that differ from each other the warning should go away as well.

Comment: You can keep both. However, as `FileNotFoundException` extends `IOException` I would remove the former and only keep the latter (assuming your method is capable of throwing other kinds of `IOException`). Then, if you want to keep "precision", explain in the _documentation_ (i.e., Javadoc, using an `@throws` tag) that the method can throw the more specific `FileNotFoundException`.